# Azure-functions: Can environment variables be used in function.json as numbers?

Tags: azure-functions

We're loading some environment variables in the function.json like so and want to set the feedpoll delay differently for our different environments. Is it possible to load a value in as an integer or some sort of number? It seems we're only able to load the feedpolldelay in as a string.

```
{
    "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
    "name": "documents",
    "direction": "in",
    "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
    "connectionStringSetting": "<connection-app-setting>",
    "databaseName": "%DBNAME%",
    "collectionName": "Items",
    "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true,
    "feedPollDelay": *target*

}
```

The issue we're having is that when trying to load the feedPollDelay, I'm unable to

Comment: `The issue we're having is that when trying to load the feedPollDelay, I'm unable to` then show the code causing said issue.

Comment: Also elaborate, "unable to". Are you getting an error when saving the file  ? error when running the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely **`host.json`** file allows to have int values in the configuraiton. You can have a look at this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file).

Comment: Probably best to wait for the OP to add more details about what error they're getting. Right now, two people have asked for clarification.